# xml xdocument, read attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to read XML document with help of XDocument. I already search over the internet for the right solution. I found this [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/reading-xml-file-through-linq-a-few-tips/), but didnt work like it should.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<blabla>
<Infos>
<ConfigurationName>XXConfigurationName</ConfigurationName>
<DateSaved>14.10.2015 10:41:54</DateSaved>
</Infos>
<Configuration>

<DayRoutine>
  <DayRoutine ID="4">
    <Button>1</Button>
    <DayRoutinePoints>
      <Point0>00:00:00, 243</Point0>
      <Point1>00:00:00, 243</Point1>
      <Point2>00:00:00, 243</Point2>
      <Point3>00:00:00, 243</Point3>
    </DayRoutinePoints>
  </DayRoutine>

  <DayRoutine ID="3">
    <Button>5</Button>
    <DayRoutinePoints>
      <Point0>00:00:00, 243</Point0>
      <Point1>00:00:00, 243</Point1>
      <Point2>00:00:00, 243</Point2>
      <Point3>00:00:00, 243</Point3>
    </DayRoutinePoints>
  </DayRoutine>
</DayRoutine>

</Configuration>
</blabla>
```

And my C# code - updated:

```
XDocument doci = XDocument.Load(path);
        var mijav = from r in doci.Descendants("Configuration").Descendants("DayRoutine").Descendants("DayRoutine").Where(r => (int)r.Attribute("ID") == 4)
                    select new
                    {
                        Button = r.Element("Button").Value,
                        DataPoints = r.Elements("DayRoutinePoints").Select(c => (string)c.Value).ToList(),
                    };
```

My Current C# code dont give me anything. I like to read data from DayRoutine ID="3". How to do that? Because I try to erase "Where(r => (int)r.Attribute("ID")==3)" and I get result from first "DayRoutine". But I like to have data from "second" DayRoutine.

And later I like to read Points. But because it is not every time the same number of points, how to read this points with some loop?

Thanks for help and please ask if you have any question

Comment: What do you mean "dont give me anything." ? The code looks sort of OK, the XML could be designed better (name the outer tag `<DayRoutines>`.

Comment: Results View come Empty back, nothing is inside.

Comment: Add a `var result = mijav.FirstOrDefault()` and tell us what's in result. I don't see a direct flaw here.

Comment: Sorry. Before I overdrive my code :) My fault. How I can read points now? It can be null points and can be all the way to 60. If I give name to point, like that: "<Point Number=0>" can help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can read points now? It can be points from 0 to 60.

This basic approach gives you the points as `XElement`s.

```
...
new 
{
   ...
   //DataPoints = r.Descendants("DayRoutinePoints").Descendants("Point1"),
     DataPoints = r.Elements("DayRoutinePoints").ToList(),
}
```

Add a `.Select(xe => ...)` before the ToList to convert to your own class.

Comment: Thanks! But i get all my string in first [0] array, are not divided into "several lines" but it is only [0] and everythink is there inside :)

Comment: variable [0] = "00:00:00, 44004:45:00, 48013:35:00, 60015:00:00, 41519:55:00, 600"

Comment: Not clear how you get that, looks like the Value of the outer DayRoutine. Edit the question.